# How do I assign a variable to my html object?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

So I have this html object that I use to display another html document:

```
<object id="questions" width="400" height="400" data="home.html">
```

But I have not been able to work out how to replace the "home.html" with a variable so i can toggle between displaying different documents.

Oh and also sorry this is badly worded I am in a hurry.

Comment: Don't use `<object>` as psuedo-`<iframe>s. `<iframe>`s are much better supported (and then you can just `<a href="other.html" target="frame">`)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object in javascript using:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('questions');
```

Then you can change the data attribute using:

```
elem.setAttribute('data', 'newValue.html');
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vWJu7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var ob = $('<object id="questions" width="400" height="400" data="home.html">')

ob.attr('data', 'google.com'); // google.com is an example.. you can put any url you like
```